# Debug output when using flyways ant tasks

Tags: flyway

The command line [documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/) mentions an argument `-x` for debug output.
However I cannot find anything in the ant task [documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/ant/).
Is there a way to activate it there as well?

Comment: In Maven there is this -X option to turn on debugs and -e for error stacktraces. May be you should try the ant options [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard `ant -d` switch to turn on the debug output.