# Flyway Ant task to show migration error without Ant's debug mode

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, migration, flyway

Almost duplicate: [Debug output when using flyways ant tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634807/debug-output-when-using-flyways-ant-tasks)

At my job, there's Ant tasks for Flyway for migrate, so a Jenkins server can execute during a deploy.

But, when a migration fails, it only shows something like

```
Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Migration of schema "public" to version X failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
```

Obviously, if I run the same task using ant -d, I get the complete error, but it's not desirable, for many reasons, that I configure the Jenkins to runs ant tasks with `ant -d`.

How can I get the complete error logging in this case?

One possible solution is creating some Java class that runs `migrate()` and calling it from Ant's `<java>` task, but I think this isn't the right thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 2.3 and you should have the failed statement included.